# voice recognition for command line interface?

Tags: command-line

i wonder if there is a good software that will run commands with voice recognition?

eg. if i say "delete temporary folder" it will delete that folder.

if i say "find symfony folder" it will find folder named symfony.

im running mac.

thanks

Comment: Yeah... *that's* a good idea.

Comment: "format see colon".... followed by the sound of an entire room full of hard disks spinning up

Comment: so are you actually planning on saying things like "see dee tilde slash" and "minus m minus u" into your microphone? seems like there's a lot of room for error here.

Comment: That's a good idea ONLY if there is not any "sh*t" or "atchoo" script that delete all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the OS. Mac OS X has had limited capabilities in this area for some time. Windows has recently added this (in Vista I think, and Windows 7).

Answer (score 2):

*That would be, were possible, nothing less but priceless ;-)*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Voice recognition cannot be used to run commands on computers. For an example of why this is true, please watch [this video demonstrating Perl Scripting to Voice Recognition](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyLqUf4cdwc).

Comment: Your link does not match what you say, a script is not a command. He asked for words, not some weird syntax that indeed causes problems on voice recognition. Voice Recognition programming is perfectly possible, you could combine Voice Recognition with Workflow Development for example.