# Run commands with voice on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, bash, voice

I use kali linux.
I want my mic to listen all the time, and when I say a word, a command executes.
I found this article about it [HERE](https://www.noobslab.com/2014/06/control-your-ubuntulinux-mint-system.html)

However, when I try the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:baitsart/voice-commands
```

I get the following error:

```
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/n/a
```

It would probably work for ubuntu, but not for Kali.
I don't know what to do..

I've also seen the superUser question [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/142203/voice-recognition-for-command-line-interface), but that is 8 years ago. Maybe things have changed?

Comment: Why don't you use Ubuntu? Kali is specifically for digital forensics and penetration testing - and for advanced users... it's not really suitable for use on a normal workstation.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Kali is for penetration testing. It's known to have trouble with standard repositories, with hardware drivers, and with lots of other things. Just switch to some other distro, like Ubuntu.